# Check whether battery level is displayed on Android

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I have a question whether it is possible to check if the battery level is currently displayed on screen on Android device. Is there a property in SDK that allows to get this information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a standard one, no. It's up to the OEM how they want to display it, which means they don't have to use the AOSP version.

Anything near-AOSP is probably using `status_bar_show_battery_percent` in Settings$System.

Samsung uses `display_battery_percentage` in Settings$System.

LG seems to use `power_save_battery_indicator` in Settings$System.

You can use `Settings.System.getInt()` to retrieve the value.